# Plot Chart Two lines, two scales, two y-axis and extra data at bottom with R and plot

Tags: r, charts, plot, lines

I'd like plot this :

[image]

And I have this data set:

```
datetime,temperature,humidity,dpv
"2014-02-15 00:00:00",67.2,13.6,"red"
"2014-02-15 00:15:00",63.4,13.8,"yellow"
"2014-02-15 00:30:00",61.2,14.2,"green"
"2014-02-15 00:45:00",60.4,14.5,"green"
```

Where `dpv` is the value for the color at bottom.

Need mix scales and put humidity at right side axis.

This is my code getting data:

```
datos_tem$datetime <- as.POSIXct(datos_tem$datetime)
datos_tem$temperature <- as.numeric(datos_tem$temperature)
datos_tem$humidity <- as.numeric(datos_tem$humidity)
```

but I don't know do it with PLOT (not ggplot2) library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the same but pretty similar:
[image]

Code:

```
datos_tem <- 
  read.csv(text=
             'datetime,temperature,humidity,dpv
           "2014-02-15 00:00:00",67.2,13.6,"red"
           "2014-02-15 00:15:00",63.4,13.8,"yellow"
           "2014-02-15 00:30:00",61.2,14.2,"green"
           "2014-02-15 00:45:00",60.4,14.5,"green"')

datos_tem$datetime <- as.POSIXct(datos_tem$datetime)
datos_tem$temperature <- as.numeric(datos_tem$temperature)
datos_tem$humidity <- as.numeric(datos_tem$humidity)
datos_tem$dpv <- as.character(datos_tem$dpv)

par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+0.1)
# add temperature
plot(datos_tem$datetime,datos_tem$temperature,typ='b',col='red',
     ylab='Temperature',xlab='Time')

# add humidity
par(new=T)
plot(datos_tem$datetime,datos_tem$humidity,type='b', 
     col='blue',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab='',ylab='')
axis(4)
mtext(side=4,text='Humidity',line=3)

# add colored bars
par(new=T)

xToler <- min(diff(datos_tem$datetime)) / 2
yToler <- (min(datos_tem$humidity) - par('usr')[3]) / 2

enc <- rle(datos_tem$dpv)

idx <- 1
for(i in 1:length(enc$lengths)){
  start <- datos_tem$datetime[idx] - xToler
  end <- datos_tem$datetime[idx + enc$lengths[i] - 1] + xToler
  rect(xleft=start,xright=end,
       ybottom=par('usr')[3],ytop=par('usr')[3]+yToler,col=enc$values[i])
  idx <- idx + enc$lengths[i]
}
```

Note:

The code is pretty generic, i.e. it automatically computes positions according to the data in the original "datos_tem" `data.frame`.

Comment: Works Fine, but Y label on the right side is lost. I suppose, it is for the size of the chart.

Comment: Have you tried again with my last modified code ? I had forgotten one line "par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+0.1)". That should add 3 lines of space on the right y axis...

Comment: @ManuParra: yes, if you copy the current code (that includes "par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+0.1)" ) and paste it into a new R session it should work as expected :)

Comment: But, at the end of the file? I wrote it, but no change happended

Comment: No, you need to call it before the first plot... look at the code in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Plots like that are recommended against.  In the case of your example plot the eye is drawn to the point where the 2 lines cross, but this point is due to arbitrary scale choice rather than anything meaningful.  Consider the change in the plot if you changed the temperature range to only go to 14 instead of 20, then the crossing point would be in a different location.  This plot draws the eye to a meaningless feature rather than emphasizing differences of interest.

Better would be to use `layout` or `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` to stack 2 plots on top of each other so the mutual increasing can still be seen, but there is no crossing point and which scale goes with which data is completely clear.

If you still insist on the inferior plot then look at `twoord.plot` in the plotrix package or `updateusr` in the TeachingDemos package (in conjunction with `plot` and `lines`).

Comment: Thanks @GregSnow, this plot is a special kind of chart, not is really scientific, but some people need represent both measures into a same chart for commodity o best comprehension. Thanks!